Destructive interference in a three-dimensional region
Typical interference patterns for electromagnetic fields show destructive interference for two-dimensional regions.
Is it possible to construct a solution of the vacuum Maxwell equations with vanishing $E(t,x) = 0$ and $B(t,x) = 0$ in a bounded three-dimensional region $U$, $ x \in U \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ with $\text{vol} \, U > 0$, in which two localized wave packets with $E_{1,2}(t,x) \neq 0$ and $B_{1,2}(t,x) \neq 0$ meet and cancel each other over a certain time $T$, i.e. $0 < t < T$?
Or the other way round, is it possible to prove that such a solution cannot exist?
We start with some region $U$, $\text{vol} \, U > 0$, $x \in U$ in the following. The two wave packets are both non-vanishing in $U$, that means they fulfil the condition (1)
$$ (E_{1,2}^2(x) + B_{1,2}^2(x) > 0 $$
or a similar condition (2)
$$ \int_U (E_{1,2}^2 + B_{1,2}^2) > 0 $$
The wave packets should be constructed such that there is destructive interference in $U$, i.e (1)
$$ (E_1(x) + E_2(x))^2 + (B_1(x) + B_2(x))^2 > 0 $$
or (2)
$$ \int_U ((E_1 + E_2)^2 + (B_1 + B_2)^2) > 0 $$
The question is if this is possible or impossible.
A trivial ansatz using two head-on wave packets constructed via Fourier transform from linear polarised plane waves fails for obvious reasons: for each wave vector $k, -k$ contributing to the wave packet, and electric field vectors $E_0, -E_0$ such that they cancel, the magnetic field vectors are
$$  \omega^{-1} k \times E_0 = \omega^{-1} (-k) \times (-E_0) $$
– so they don’t cancel but point into the same direction.
Remark: Reasoning based on vector potentials might be misleading because it's not the the amplitude of the potential carrying the energy but the derivatives, i.e. the electric and the magnetic field.

You will not find a U with vol>0 for complete vanishing. Same in two dimension, You can go from 2 dim to 3 dim just moving the screen used in 2d,

So you say, already 2-dim. areas with reconstructive interference are forbidden? I don’t see a simple reason for that; based on the Poynting vector it's allowed. So please explain way.

I don't know what reconstructive interference is? I also don't see what the pointing vector has to do with it. can you point out in 2 d a  2 dimensional region with complete vanishing E?

Sorry for the typo, destructive interference, of course.

The Poynting equation says that $\dot{u} + \nabla S = 0$. For one time $t_0$ on a 2-dim surface $\Sigma$ we could have $u|{t_0, \Sigma} = 0$ but $\dot{u}|{t_0, \Sigma} \neq 0$ and $\nabla S |_{t_0, \Sigma} \neq 0$. So the Poynting equation is satisfied, there is destructive interference on the entire surface, yet the surface is moving.

Something similar must be possible. Let us start with the fact that free EM fields satisfy the d'Alembert equation
$$-\frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial^2 f(t,\vec{x})}{\partial t^2}+ \Delta_{\vec{x}} f(t,\vec{x})=0\tag{1}\label{eq:1}$$
where $f$ is any of the components of $\vec{E}$, $\vec{B}$.
Consider an open ball $B_r$ of radius $r$  centered at the origin of spatial axes at $t=0$, and suppose that both $f(t,\vec{x})$ and $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial t}(t, \vec{x})$ vanish in $B_r$ and take suitable smooth values outside that ball. We can also assume that the function vanishes (always at $t=0$) outside a larger ball $B_R$ with $R \gg r$.
In view of the hyperbolic structure of $\eqref{eq:1}$:

(a) there is a unique solution defined for all $(t,\vec{x})\in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^3$ which matches the said initial data;

(b) in particular, in the double spacetime cone with basis $B_r$ and height (on both temporal directions) $r/c$, the solution is uniquely determined by the values of the initial conditions in $B_r$. Since the equation is linear and the field vanishes in $B_r$, the only solution in the double cone is the zero solution;

(c) outside that double cone, in the past and in the future, the field generally does not vanish due to the contributions of the initial data propagating there from the region outside $B_r$.


That double cone includes a sufficiently small cylinder $[-T,T] \times B_{r/2}$ where the solution is zero.
Physically speaking, the process can be seen as due to destructive interference of the field with itself.
Indeed, if you change the origin of time in the past at $t_0 \ll -r/c$ and you keep the found solution, you see a field that, at the (new) initial time, is generally no-vanishing around the spatial origin and, after a while, a $r/2$-radius ball of zero field creates in that region, and it disappears after $\sim 2r/c$ seconds.
Vice versa, a solution such that the field vanishes exactly in a set of the form $[-T, T]\times B_r$ cannot exist. Necessarily, it must also vanish at least inside the solid cones, future and past, with base $B_r$ at times $\pm T$.
In $1+1$ dim, these facts are evident consequences of the d'Alembert form of the solution.
$$f(t,x) =  \frac{1}{2}( f(0,x-ct) + f(0,x+ct)) + \frac{1}{2c}\int\limits_{x-ct}^{x+ct}\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(0,s) \, \mathrm{d}s $$
when resetting the origin of time, respectively, at $\pm T$. There, by hypothesis, both the field and its temporal derivative vanish. Using the above formula, one immediately sees that the field must also vanish in the double cones with the said bases and thus also outside $[-T,T]\times B_r$.

Thanks. I am not sure if I really get the point. In (b) you are saying that if the field vanishes in $B_r$, then it vanishes in the entire double spacetime cone with basis $B_r$. Am I right?

But my question was if it's possible to construct such a solution vanishing in $B_r$ from two non-vanishing wave packets cancelling only within $B_r$, not outside. You are saying that this is not possible, they must cancel in the entire double cone. Is this correct?

There is a counter example in 1+1 dim. for a massless scalar field. Your argument is rather generic, so I think that it does not exclude this example: We have two wave packets $\phi_\pm = \pm f(x \pm ct)$. The solution is $\phi = \phi_+ + \phi_-$. $f(x)$ is nonzero over a certain range, zero otherwise. If $f(x)$ is constant over some range of $x$, then for $t=0$ we have $\phi=0$ in that range (the energy sits in the region where $f$ changes from zero to nonzero. So I guess we must be more specific regarding the properties of the electromagnetic field.

So, in spacetime the wanted solution is zero only in a set of this form:$ [-T,T] \times B_r$. Is it correct? I mean, should $B_r$ not deform during the considered lapse of time?

However, yes,  if the two packets cancel in $B_r$ for an arbitrarily small temporal neighborhood of $t=0$, they also must cancel at least in the double cone with basis $B_r$ in spacerime. Your example in 1+1 dim also satisfies it.

The requirement is that they cancel in a spatial region $B_r$ with non-vanishing volume $\text{vol} , B_r \neq$ for an instant of time. Then it seems plausible that they must cancel in some larger region of spacetime. I think I am struggling with the meaning of double-cone. Is it the same as a causal diamond https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_structure#/media/File:PhysRevD.99.086006_Fig2_CausalDiamond.png?

Anyway, I think the discussion about scalar fields goes into the wrong direction. My original question was about the electromagnetic field, i.e. $E^2 + B^2 = 0$ in some $B_r$. It's not about two wave packets where the two non-vanishing potentials $A_{1,2}$ cancel in in some $B_r$, but about two wave packets where the two non-vanishing fields $E_{1,2}$, $B_{1,2}$  cancel. I'll clarify that in the original question.

Yes a double cone is a causal diamond. Regarding your last comment: every component of $E$ and $B$ satisfies the scalar equation so that, in my view, the problem can be decomposed in terms of fields satisfying the scalar equation.

Thanks for clarifying the double-cone. Yes, each component satisfies one scalar equation, but the equations for $E$ and $B$ are not independent. I mentioned that in the question: for plane waves – and therefore for all wave packets constructed via Fourier transform – not both $E$ and $B$ can cancel due to the orientation of the vectors $k, E, B$.

I understand, thanks. However the only  fact that they satisfy d’Alembert equation implies that reasoning with causal diamonds. Hence, the region in spacetime where the fields vanish cannot be a simple cylinder…

That's fine, thanks. I don't insist on a specific region. My problem is that I have no clue how to solve the problem for both electric and magnetic field.
